# $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ and $f(0)=1$. Finding $f''(0)$ rapidly.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let be $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ and $f(0)=1$.
I have to find $f''(0)$. I tried to solve it with finding the second derivative of the function and after that using the L'Hospital rule more times. But this takes a lot of time, more than I have therefor on my exam. Is there a way to find $f''(0)$ faster?

Comment: How can $f(0)$ be 1.

Comment: You certainly don't want to differentiate the function by using rules of it? Right?

Comment: No, but if we just put 0 in the equation we don't get 1

Comment: @user2369284: I assume $x=0$ is a removable discont.

Comment: @B.S.: Yes, I don't want to find the derivative of the expression with the derivative rules, the solution of robjohn is the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: @ramez: I knew that. It is an elegant post. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hint:** If you can use Taylor Series, you could find the series:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{e^x-1}{x}
&=\frac{\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots\right)-1}{x}\\
&=1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\dots
\end{align}
$$
and take two derivatives at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve using the derivative definition. The first derivative is:
$f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{e^h-1}{h}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h-h-1}{h^2}$.
Now using L'Hopital rule you have 
$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^h-1}{2h}=\frac{1}{2}$.
With the same method we compute the second derivative in zero, that is
$f''(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(h)-f'(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(\frac{e^h -h-1}{h^2}-\frac{1}{2})\frac{1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2he^h-2e^h+2-h^2}{2h^3}$. Using L'Hopital 
$f''(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2e^h+2he^h-2e^h-2h}{6h^2}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{2(e^h-1)}{6h}=\frac{1}{3}$